# Difference between holding a reference of class in _init_ and calling it inside another class

Tags: python, security

I am currently working on a project in which security has an important role and I am not sure on which of the following ways should I apply in the project.

```
class First():
    def some_function(self):
        print('this is a function')

class Second():
    def second_other_function(self):
        First().some_function()
        print('this is another function')

class Second():
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = First()
    def some_other_function(self):
        self.first.some_function()
        print('this is another function')
```

What would be the better solution between the First() class and one of the Second() classes, if I do not want the second class to be associated with the first, as in not access it.

Thank you

Comment: *Security*, what kind of security? Also keep in mind that the two codes you provided behave differently. With the first one you will have a new instance of `First` everytime `Second.second_other_function` is called.

Comment: @DeepSpace first is acting as Model, second as controller in an mvc pattern

Comment: Not really. The only difference is that the first code creates a new instance of `First` and then dumps it (whenever the GC decides to). The second code keeps a reference to the same `First` object.

Comment: @DeepSpace okay, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between the two examples is that the first one creates a new instance of `First` and then dumps it (whenever the GC decides to). The second keeps a reference to the same `First` object.

The first approach is quite wasteful (new objects will be created and thrown away every single time `Second.second_other_function` is called), and I suspect that what you are really after is a static method:

```
class First():
    @staticmethod
    def some_function():
        print('this is a function')

class Second():
    def second_other_function(self):
        First.some_function()
        print('this is another function')
```

This then begs the question if you even need the `First` class.

Comment: I think the first class would be needed cause thats where the queries in the database happen. second class just deals with the requests.